# SVN to GIT Migration with commit history (Using git svn)

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migration

I need to migrate a repository from SVN to GIT(Bitbiucket) along with commit history and branches. Read and explored few posts but getting stuck when tried the below commands from the following url:
https://davidzych.com/migrating-from-svn-to-git/

```
Step 1) git svn init http://url.to.svn/ --prefix svn
Step 2) git svn init http://url.to.svn/ -T Trunk -B Branches -t Tags
Step 3) git config svn.authorsfile ../authors.txt
Step 4) git svn fetch [Get stuck at this step and it doesn't move forward after a specific revision]
Step 5) git branch -a
Step 6) git tag -a -m "Migrating SVN tag" tag-name refs/tags/tag-name
Step 7) git remote add newrepo https://url.to.git/repo.git
Step 8) git push --all newrepo and git push --tags newrepo
```

I have also tried the steps from the below url.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-new-repo?view=azure-devops

Please do suggest if there is any other better way/steps to do this migration.

Answer (score 0):

There's a special plugin for that for Bitbucket, called SVN Mirror.

Comment: Are there any manual steps which can be done for the same purpose. I have a plan of using SVN mirror plugin as the last option (as it is not free).

Comment: As far as I know, there's a 30-day trial on it. If you don't need to keep SVN and Git in sync for a long time, just migrate once, then the trial time should be enough for you.